# Motorola DS 4208 barcode scanner not detected in .NET 64 bit machines

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, pos-for-.net

Im working on a POS application that needs to make use of motorola ds4208 barcode scanner.

I installed the motorola sdk for windows , and the OPOS sample application works well with the device.

But when i try to use this device in my app... I use

posexplorer.getDevices()

it dsnt detect the scanner. I tried using SOMgr to check the service object , but still nothing in it.

The same works on a 32 bit machine though. Tried on multiple 64 bit machines, didnt work.

I tried installing CCO , still no luck.

I tried manually adding a configuration.xml file with motorolascanner service objec, still dsnt work.

Any directions or pointers on what could be going wrong??

Comment: Well, if it works in 32-bit, your app is probably built to target 64-bit, and you haven't installed the 64-bit drivers. If that's the case, you should either set your app to target 32-bit .NET, or install a 64-bit version of the drivers that will work with your 64-bit app.

Comment: I installed 64 bit drivers and its not just my app... even SOMgr isnt detecting it as a POS device,

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the age of the service object you're trying to use.  According to this page from MS:

[POS for .NET Support on 64-Bit Editions of Microsoft Windows Operating Systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959944)

> Legacy controls and service objects are based on 32-bit COM.
>   Therefore, the host application must be started in a 32-bit process if
>   it wishes to support such legacy OPOS controls and service objects.

So, depending on your device and the driver support provided for it, you may be forced to run your application targeting x86 CPU's.